# Помогите расставить знаки препинания (5)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, двоеточие, перечисление

Помогите, пожалуйста, со знаками препинания в этом предложении.

> Если требуется сделать картину на заказ, то мы согласовываем основные моменты: где размещается работа, каковы предпочтительный стиль и техника исполнения, определяемся с размерами и сюжетом.

Смущает запятая перед "определяемся". Это ведь продолжение фразы перед двоеточием, не нужно ли по логике поставить тире или запятую и тире?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно предложить такой вариант:

*Если требуется сделать картину на заказ, то мы согласовываем основные моменты: где размещается работа, каковы предпочтительный стиль и техника исполнения, **а также определяемся с размерами и сюжетом.***

**Пояснение**

Использование союза А ТАКЖЕ  позволяет четко **обозначить границу** внутри однородного ряда, когда первый однородный член значительно **распространен.** При этом союз не воспринимается как однозначно присоединительный, то есть значение **равноправия** членов сохраняется.

Это можно наблюдать в текстах из Нацкорпуса, где  А ТАКЖЕ  только выделяет и подчеркивает **каждый** из однородных членов, обозначая указанную границу.

Например (в действительности примеров очень много):

*В связи с развёртыванием этих, **а также** и других немаловажных предприятий начало стремительно полнеть население города…*

*Хотя львы на воротах и стаи галок на крестах, **а также** аптеки, фонари, бульвары и прочее ещё имелись в большом количестве*. [В. П. Катаев. Алмазный мой венец (1975-1977)]

Answer (score 3):

Второй ответ  от 12.04.2021

Более подробное обоснование первого ответа

1. **Есть ли добавочное значение у союза А ТАКЖЕ**

Присмотримся к союзу А ТАКЖЕ, он соединительный или присоединительный?  Кустова называет А ТАКЖЕ присоединительным союзом  только для однородных членов (значение добавочности **в пределах** однородного ряда!), то есть это не классическая присоединительная конструкция. В теме сложных предложений союз А ТАКЖЕ  в качестве присоединительного союза вообще не называется. А вот союз ТАКЖЕ однозначно назван там  **соединительным**.

**А как думаю я?** Я использую этот союз часто, причем именно в таких ситуациях: первый однородный член (или весь ряд) значительно **распространен**.  Мне в этом случае  надо просто **обозначить границы**, а не придавать последнему однородному члену значение присоединения – он у меня равноправен с другими членами.

Мне представляется правильным такое определение функции союза. Союз А ТАКЖЕ – это составной союз. Вероятно, основной часть следует считать союз ТАКЖЕ, а  союз А именно технический, он определяет границы при однородных отношениях.

2. **Скобки – это не всегда верно**

…*то мы согласовываем основные моменты (**где размещается работа, каковы предпочтительный стиль и техника исполнения)**, определяемся с размерами и сюжетом.*

Что дает понимание союза А ТАКЖЕ в  качестве соединительного? Прекрасную возможность обойтись **без скобок**, когда нет оснований заключать в скобки достаточно **важную** информацию.

Скобки – это удобный для редакторов знак, мне тоже сначала хотелось поставить скобки. Но  я вспомнила о том, что писатели иногда категорически против того, чтобы их произведение «украшали» скобками. Мне они тоже представляются сейчас уходом от решения задачи, хотя в технических случаях я ими пользуюсь (для передачи текущей информации). Но это должен быть выбор **автора**, а не редакторов.

**3. Правила применяются для конкретной грамматики**

Не стоит необоснованно расширять границы, то есть применять правило для обычных однородных членов с обобщающим словом к сложным конструкциям, где использованы не члены ряда, а **целые предложения.** Такая связь выглядит как бессоюзная и требует особого подхода.

4. **А как быть с тире?**

…*то мы согласовываем основные моменты: размещение работы, предпочтительный стиль и технику исполнения **— определяемся с размерами и сюжетом.***

Я думаю, что тире сюда не подойдет: ведь это не обобщение, а скорее равные однородные отношения. По крайней мере, здесь опять же требуется согласование с автором.

Comment: _Но я вспомнила о том, что писатели иногда категорически против того, чтобы их произведение «украшали» скобками._ К великому сожалению, я **такого утверждения** не знаю. Но помню, что некоторые известные писатели категорически **не против** использования скобок — и это никоим образом не портит их повествования. Вот (Роберт Гэлбрейт. Шелкопряд): в совсем небольшом отрывке восемь(!) предложений со скобками. (https://www.litres.ru/robert-gelbreyt/shelkopryad/chitat-onlayn/page-2/)

Comment: Римма, вас все-таки обидел отзыв, и это чувствуется, извините.  В свое оправдание я отмечу следующее. У каждого автора свой стиль, свои задачи в передаче нужного смысла. Возможно, кому-то очень нравятся скобки, и это может быть даже стилевой особенностью их текстов. Поэтому я использую слово «иногда» и подчеркиваю, что это выбор автора, а не редакторов. Скобки –  самый сильный знак для обозначения добавочного значения, поэтому он не всегда подходит.

Answer (score 2):

Вы правы в том, что в конце перечисления нельзя ставить запятую, но здесь, вероятно, не заканчивается перечисление перед словом «определяемся». Разве размер и сюжет могут не быть основными согласовываемыми моментами? Размер уж точно не может не быть таким моментом.

Answer (score 2):

При такой конструкции предложения можно и не понять, что "определяемся" является однородным с "согласовываем".

Во избежание двоякого понимания я бы написала так (со скобками):
*Если требуется сделать картину на заказ, то мы **согласовываем** основные моменты (где размещается работа, каковы предпочтительный стиль и техника исполнения), **определяемся** с размерами и сюжетом.*

Или так (согласовываем [*что? какие именно моменты?*] — перечисление в В. п.):
*Если требуется сделать картину на заказ, то мы согласовываем **основные моменты**: **размещение** работы, предпочтительный **стиль** и **технику** исполнения — определяемся с размерами и сюжетом.*

**Уточнение**

В конце перечисления, конечно же, **может** ставиться запятая, если к **последнему** из членов этого ряда относится обособленный член предложения:
*И везде: в санпоездах, в госпиталях, средь инвалидов, толкущихся в приёмных разных комиссий, даже будучи в доме отдыха, **в Краснокамске, —** Федя Скворцов осторожно интересовался насчёт Синицыной Вики* (В. Астафьев. Рассказы).

[Знаки препинания при однородных членах предложения с обобщающими словами](https://dict.nsu.ru/mod/book/view.php?id=12&chapterid=51)